# Jquery: How to build / update a GET Request containing many variables

Tags: jquery, get

I dont know how to do this, maybe someone can push me in a direction!

I have a form containing some dropdown and some checkboxes, I want to collect all the data and make a GET Request.
For the checkboxes i want to use "," between the values. 
To do so I got through every form element separately.

But I dont know how can I update the GET Request when the data changed?

```
       /*   Dropdown: */

        $('#filter').on('change', 'select[name="jahr"]', function(){        
        jahr_val = $(this).val();   
        /*  Update the Query */
        });



         /*     Dropdown: */
        $('#filter').on('change', 'select[name="saison"]', function(){
        saison_val = $(this).val();     
        /*  Update the Query */ 
        });



         /*     Checkboxes: */
        $('#filter').on('click', 'input[name="typ"]', function(){
            var $typ_val = $(this).val();
                typ_vals = [];
        $('#filter').find('input[name="typ"]:checked').each(function(){
            typ_vals.push( $(this).val() );
            });
            typ_vals = typ_vals.join(",");


             /*     Update the Query  */
        });



        /*  Checkboxes: */
        $('#filter').on('click', 'input[name="tag"]', function(){                   
            var $tag_val = $(this).val();
                tag_vals = [];
        $('#filter').find('input[name="tag"]:checked').each(function(){
                tag_vals.push( $(this).val() );
            });
            tag_vals = tag_vals.join(",");

         /*     Update the Query */


        });
```

Thank you very much for any help!!!

Comment: by update the get request do you mean you want to trigger the request when there is any change in dropdowns/checkbox?

Comment: yes, when the user did a selection I want to start a get request. f.e. like this "       window.location.replace('pathto/?typ=' + typ_vals+ "&tag=" tag_vals"…);"

Comment: If you want to reload the current page you can do this window.location.href = "pathto/?params". Or if it as an ajax request that you are looking to call create a method that calls your get request based on some parameters and call it on the change events of your dropdown/checkbox. Refer this for more info about ajax get request  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: yes, i want to reload the current page, I dont want to use a ajax request a simple get request fits better. My main question is how can I build up the get request. At the moment I have multiple jquery functions but I need something like one get-string containing the values from each function. Sorry to be not so clear! Thank you very much!

Comment: to be more clear:
After the visitor uses the form I need to build up the get-query containing the different values from the different form elements (dropdown, checkbox etc).

Comment: ok I found a very easy solution for me I will use Post instead of Get and I will not use Jquery/Ajax at the moment, I only use Jquery to fire the submit button when the form is changed. This seems very easy but  I think it will work and I dont need any fallback for users without js. Thanks!